# Why is Flutter not generating the internationalization files?

Tags: flutter, internationalization

I'm trying to follow the internationalization documentation in https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#dart-tools and https://docs.google.com/document/d/10e0saTfAv32OZLRmONy866vnaw0I2jwL8zukykpgWBc/edit#heading=h.upcu5w85cvc2 but it's not generating any files.

Basically it says to make these mods to the pub `spec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2
flutter:
  generate: true
```

Then create a `<project-root>/l10n.yaml` file containing:

```
arb-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: app_en.arb
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart
```

And finally to create the `app_en.arb` with something like this:

```
{
  "@@locale": "en",

  "helloWorld": "Hello World!",
  "@helloWorld": {
    "description": "The conventional newborn programmer greeting"
  }
}
```

And from there the guides say that a `flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart` file will be automatically generated.

Except that nothing happens. I'm working in Android Studio and did a `pub get`, and tried a `flutter clean` and `flutter build ios` and everything else I can't think of but nothing is building that file.

Any ideas?

Comment: For me, it was writing `i10n` instead of `l10n` for the file name and `.yaml` config name.

Comment: @ArieDov The name is indeed `l10n` (lowercase L) , not `i10n`. If that worked for you, that means you messed it up with the name somewhere else.

Comment: OMG, I just noticed that my localization files were not being auto generated on app run because I had created the file `l10n.yaml` inside the `lib/` folder. But it clearly says `to the root directory of the Flutter project`. I changed the location and now it works as expected.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Ok. done some more digging and I've solved it. Basically the Flutter documentation is slightly out of date.

Firstly, the generated files are being generated, but they're in **`<project_dir>.dart_tools/flutter_gen/genl10n`**. The generator creates a synthetic package that is automatically available to the project so there is no need for any further `pubspec.yaml` changes.

Secondly, your `main.dart` has to look like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
      supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
      title: 'My app',
      home: ... ,
    );
  }
}
```

Two things here:

1. The importing of the `app_localizations.dart` generated file (which the docs do mention but perhaps not explain well) and ...
2. Changing the `localizationsDelegates` and `supportedLocales`. You don't need to list all the delegates and locales mentioned in the docs as the generated localisation files automatically include them. Just switch to the two properties of `AppLocalizations`.

#### PS

After writing the above I attempted to internationalise the app's title:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
      supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
      title: AppLocalizations.of(context).applicationTitle,
      home: ... ,
    );
  }
```

Epic fail - The reason is that at the time it goes to resolve the title, the delegates and locales have not yet been set so what comes back from `AppLocalizations.of(context)` is a `null`. Instead you need to change to the `onGeneratedTitle` like this:

````dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
      supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
      onGenerateTitle: (context) => AppLocalizations.of(context).applicationTitle,
      home: ... ,
    );
  }
```.  

`onGeneratedTitle` is called after the widget is setup which means localisation is available.
````

Comment: I gave up the native solution and changed to use `IDE plugin` like (https://localizely.com/flutter-localization-workflow). Do `Dart intl tools` also generate translation code automatically?

Comment: Not that I can see. Nothing obviously in there about handling translations. After I got it working, I downloaded an app Babel which is an editor for *arb files. It's a little quirky, in places but on the whole seems to work well and I like the fact it automatically runs google translate for me. Kinda like cheating without having to learn the language first. Hopefully it's reasonable accurate :-)

Answer (score 117):

Addition to @drekka answer,

You need to run

```
flutter gen-l10n
```

If it's not generated automatically.

Comment: Thank you!
It is not so well documented as in my case translations were automatically generated but i wanted to generate them without having to run the app.

Comment: actually when there are missing translations, running the app through vscode is not possible until generating the l10n files manually gets done, TY

Comment: $ flutter gen-l10n

Because l10n.yaml exists, the options defined there will be used instead.
To use the command line arguments, delete the l10n.yaml file in the Flutter project.

Answer (score 28):

Faced similar issue when needed to generate these files through CLI without IDE at all (on CircleCI).

First, you should have `intl_utils` either as project dependency or activated globally.

To install it as a dependency (and manage its version per project) - just add `intl_utils: ^2.1.0` to the `dependencies` section of your `pubspec.yaml` (don't forget to set the version you need). After that, from the project directory run:

```
flutter gen-l10n --template-arb-file=intl_en.arb
flutter pub run intl_utils:generate
```

(change `intl_en.arb` to your actual `.arb` file name or omit the whole parameter in case it matches the default `app_en.arb`)

To activate `intl_utils` globally (and use a single version of `intl_utils` on all your projects), do the following:

```
dart pub global activate intl_utils 2.1.0
```

And then run this from the project directory:

```
flutter gen-l10n --template-arb-file=intl_en.arb
dart pub global run intl_utils:generate
```

In my case, since the project hasn't yet migrated to use null safety, having `intl_utils` as project dependency led to null safety issues, so the trick was to use `intl_utils 1.9.0` globally.

Comment: How can you then use the text
in the original case we use AppLocalizations.of(context).helloWorld

Answer (score 17):

Run this on your terminal or command-line:
**dart pub global activate intl_utils 2.1.0**
OR
**dart pub global run intl_utils:generate**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 7):

I've run into this same issue right now. I don't know why this is happening, but I've found this [post](https://www.raywenderlich.com/10794904-internationalizing-and-localizing-your-flutter-app) providing the same information and decided to try using the plugin it mentions.

The plugin is called "Flutter Intl" and is available for [Android Studio](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13666-flutter-intl) and [VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=localizely.flutter-intl). You'll need to install it in your IDE and run the "Flutter Intl: initialize" command. This action should create the "lib/generated" folder with all the needed boilerplate.

Comment: Yep, I've seen that, but I need to build the app on Bitrise which means building without Android studio. So I don't think that will work. :-(

Comment: See my response above as to how to fix this.

Comment: i install plugin in android studio IDE but not getting "lib/generated"

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem. Accidentally found out that I had created l10n.yaml in the `lib` dir instead of base dir. Moved it where it should be, and everything worked!

Comment: lol I just noticed this was my issue right before reading your answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you add this code in pubspec.yaml it is automatically generated

```
flutter_intl:
  enabled: true
  class_name: AppLocalizations
```

Answer (score 3):

`flutter pub cache clean` helped in this case

Answer (score 1):

If you have the intl plugin in your code editor (Android Studio) then you should have this generated folder (`lib/generated/l10n.dart`).

Run this command in your terminal

```
flutter pub run intl_utils:generate
```

then after it will be work.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, it seems that VsCode (for my case) doesn't see the recent update of the generated `app_localizations.dart` file.

**To solve this issue, simply open the generated file located here :**

`.dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart`

You should see your `app_localizations.dart` file updated

As a reminder, after editing your `.arb` file, you need to launch `flutter pub get` to get the latest changes.

Answer (score 1):

At home, there was a connection problem, I have tools > Flutter > flutter upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I imported the project from another developer and none of the solutions helped me. You have to delete everything after adding the dependency and start the program once. Then this file is created. Only then can you import the file into the class and work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem , I was using vs code, just restart vs code and everything will work just fine.